# Riemann Integrable Functions to prove $f(x) =0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and that $\int_a^b fdx = 0$.

Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: The next section of the question says to:

Show that the continuity hypothesis cannot be dropped.

I am stuck :(

Comment: For the part in the next section consider $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in[a,b)$ with $f(b) = 1$. What is $\int_a^b f(x) dx$?